# Is it possible to document fields in a record in clojure?

Tags: clojure

For example:

```
(defrecord Contract [^{:doc "primary identifiers..."} contract-id])
```

But this doesn't seem to work:

```
(doc Contract)

clojure.lang.Cons cannot be cast to clojure.lang.Symbol
[Thrown class java.lang.ClassCastException]
```

Maybe you can't document record fields?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

defrecord compiles a new class and uses these names as the fields of that class. Unfortunatly classes predate clojure and leave no room for metadata :(

```
The class will have the (immutable) fields named by
fields, which can have type hints.
```